# "select cast(UUID() as VARBINARY(100))" MySQL query error

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariasql

**Error:**

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARBINARY(10))' at line 1

Comment: Please include the full query.

Comment: You'd almost assume it was the title, except for the 100->10 discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

`VARBINARY` isn't a type (data types in columns are slightly different)

I think you want something like:

```
select cast(UUID() as CHAR(36) CHARACTER SET  BINARY)
```

Comment: It is giving out put like BLOB.